# `ERROR 9001 (HY000): PD server timeoutstart timestamp may fall behind safepoint` in TiDB

Tags: distributed-database, tidb, tidb-pd

When I was testing TiDB, I bumped into the 9001 error. I didn't figure out the cause. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error occurs when TiDB fails to access PD. There is a “worker” in the background of TiDB that continuously queries the safepoint from PD. If the query is not successful within 100s, this error is reported.

Possible causes: PD failure or the network issue between TiDB and PD. Solution: Check the state/monitor/log of the PD server and the network between the TiDB server and the PD server.